# My Ajax code isn't working.

Tags: ajax

"text.txt" is located in the same folder as the html file so that shouldn't be the problem. I want to change the h4 header to the text within the text file

```
function load_doc(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("ajax_example").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","text.txt",true);
    xhttp.send();
}


<div id="ajax_example">
    <h4>Request Object</h4>
    <button type="button" onclick="load_doc()">Change Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try to console.log xhttp.responseText to see if you get something

Comment: Didn't work. Do you mean: document.getElementById("ajax_example").innerHTML = console.log(xhttp.responseText)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with full path specification?
something like

```
xhttp.open('GET', 'file:///home/user/text.txt', true);
```